# PHP Redirect Depending On User Type

Tags: php

I have a login page that fairly basic. I'm developing a prototype whilst learning the in's and outs of PHP.

In my MySql database, it looks like this:
UserID, username, passcode, talent, customer. Talent and customer are both binary and only one can be True.

So what I'm trying to do, is if talent = 1, send them to index.php, and if customer = 1, send them to recruiter.php.

I'm 90% sure I have the basics down, but since I've added the extra if's to check talent and customer, it's broken my script :)

Finally, I'd need to do this check on each page to make sure that customers don't access talent pages and visa versa.

Am I on the right track??

My current script does this:

```
     <?php
        include("resource/config.php");
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
        // username and password sent from Form 
            $myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
            $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']); 

            $sql="SELECT UserID, talent, customer FROM useradmin WHERE username='$myusername' and passcode='$mypassword'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $active=$row['active'];
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

        if ($row['talent']==1) {
                if ($count==1) {
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
                    header("location: index.php");
                }
                else {
                    $error="Your Email or Password is invalid";
                }
            }    
        elseif ($row['customer']==1) {
                if ($count==1) {
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
                    header("location: recruiter.php");
                }
                else {
                    $error="Your Email or Password is invalid";
                }
            }

        else {
            $error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Also, at the top of every page I have this, to make sure only a logged in user can access it.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from useradmin where username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);

$login_session=$row['username'];

if(!isset($login_session)) {
     header("Location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: One thing, your `$error` variable. I don't see it anywhere else and seems to be unassigned. If it is not assigned, then you need to do this `echo "Your Email or Password is invalid";` etc. that's "IF" `$error` is not used anywhere else and do the same for the other one also.

Comment: have you var_dump($row)? as @dleiftah said you should use the appropriate syntax

Comment: @Fred-ii- no it's not doing anything at the moment. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: Do you also have `session_start();` inside your `config.php` file?

Comment: @dleiftah, sorry I've updated my script, I did try that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no but it is at the top of this file?

Comment: @Mcam435 You probably could put `session_start();` inside your config file or place it underneath your call to it.

Comment: var_dump($row) and show result

Comment: @Fred-ii- have popped it in there now. It's working using Vlad and Mike's answers now.

Comment: @Mcam435 Right on, glad to hear it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Would it just be a simple 3 liner script at the top for the second part of the question? "Finally, I'd need to do this check on each page to make sure that customers don't access talent pages and visa versa."?? Or, even a hint on what to google, I'm actually completely stumped on this part.

Comment: @Mcam435 Yes, `session_start();` must be inside all pages being used for the same purpose, which if you are using the same include for your config, it can be inside that, just as long as it's present in all pages.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry just updated my script to show what I have at the top of all "member only" page. This makes sure people are logged in, but doesn't check if their user type is allowed to access the page.

Comment: @Mcam435 Have a look at this, I keep this handy at all times http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html it's a really good read and will make sure that if a user's session doesn't match, it won't give access. It uses both sessions and tokens. (mostly the last entry)

Comment: That's a great link. Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do a comparison like this:

```
if (['talent']==1)
```

You likely are wanting to compare like this:

```
if ($row['talent']==1)
```

In essence what you were doing was comparing an array with a single element of `talent` against `1`.

Comment: Thank you for this and the explanation on what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `if ($row['talent']==1)` and `elseif ($row['customer']==1)`

Comment: Was sure I tried that. It's working now though thank you very much. There's also the part about preventing the different user types accessing the other pages, or is it only 1 question per 'question'? :)

Comment: Oops...You could set a $relationship var in your login script, then check if the user's $relationship == 'customer' or whatever. I would like to point out that it's not a good idea to insert user input directly into your SQL.